# how to shoot a player using photon in unity and then show the arrow in both players screen?

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

i want to shoot player with arrow both players are instantiated by photon network in the scene and I want to show player and at the same time I want to show arrow in both player screens. But I don't know how to do it with a photon.
Please help :)

Comment: Use [PhotonNetwork.Instantiate](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/current/gameplay/instantiation), which will spawn the object across the network.

Comment: ok, let me try if it works or not

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.